# Cannot able to connect socket.io in Flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket, socket.io, flutter-dependencies, flutter-pub

I am trying to connect socket.io using this package `socket_io_client: ^2.0.0` when I tried to connect it gets a timeout on `onConnectionError`. I have shared my code below

```
socket.Socket webSocket = socket.io(constant.demoSocketUrl,
<String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': false,
  });
  socket.Socket sol;


webSocket.connect();


webSocket.onConnect((data) {
  print(data);
});
webSocket.on('connect', (_) => print('connect: ${webSocket.id}'));
webSocket.emit("joinTradePairRoom");
webSocket.on("trade_pair_room", (data) {
  print( "˚˚˚ $data");
});
webSocket.onConnectError((data) => print('øøøø $data'));
webSocket.on('joinTradePairRoom', (data){
print("˚˚˚ $data");
});
```